# Is there a way to validate what is in an object in the cypress version 12 test

Tags: javascript, object, cypress

here I am validating that this object exists in the response

```
expect(response.body).to.have.property('cadastro');
```

How do I validate what's inside this object?
I tried to insert what I had in the object:

```
expect(cadastro).to.deep.equal({
})
```

I expected the test to verify that all items are returning

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.